# Error when trying to check typeof undefined json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

When Im trying to check if the [action] is defined I keep getting javascript errors.

```
    if((typeof array_from_php.api_description[mobile_type][action]) != 'undefined') {
        console.log('defined');
        api = array_from_php.api_description[mobile_type][action];
    } else {
        console.log('undefined');
        mobile_type = 0;
        api = array_from_php.api_description[mobile_type][action];
    }
```

Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register_mobile' of undefined

Comment: I can't see this `register_mobile` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check each property like

```
if(array_from_php && array_from_php.api_description && array_from_php.api_description[mobile_type] && (typeof array_from_php.api_description[mobile_type][action]) != 'undefined') {
    console.log('defined');
    api = array_from_php.api_description[mobile_type][action];
} else {
    console.log('undefined');
    mobile_type = 0;
    api = array_from_php.api_description[mobile_type][action];
}
```